# Best way to merge master Git repo into private one, if private one has few changes

Tags: git

I have used CVS, SVN and Mercurial, trying to find the 'right' way with Git, often is a challenge.

I forked a public git Repo to a private Gitlab server. Over time, only a few files were modified. Now I want to update my local version to the latest version of the public repo and merge the changes from the (few) locally changed files into this new version.

A simple pull or fetch->merge seems to me not the proper way to do it.
Would rebase here a better option ?
I am using TortoiseGit, I do now know it that imposes any limitations.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- your working branch name is `master`.
- your working tree is clean (run `git status` to verify)

You can try the following:

1. `git checkout -b temp <hash-of-the-fork-commit>` - Will create and checkout a new branch named `temp` that points to where the repositories forked.
2. `git pull origin master` - Will pull all remote changes to `temp` branch.
3. `git merge master` - Will apply your changes on top of the remote ones.

So you will end up with your `master` and a `temp` branch that has all the changes.

After verifying that everything is ok, you can replace `master` with `temp` using:

1. `git branch -d master` - deletes `master`
2. `git checkout -b master` - creates a new `master`
3. `git branch -d temp` - deletes `temp` branch.

Comment: I had to lookup how to do some steps with Tortoise, but it did exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Waldorf thats good to know, have a great day!